# how to set up a ldap server on centos 6.3

Tags: ldap, centos

Can any one provide me a documentation for setting up ldap server on centos machine.I googled a lot but couldn't find proper document.I want to use LDAPv3 Directory services in my LDAP server

Comment: Does this help?: http://wiki.openiam.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7635198